# Testing a chained set of commands with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following code:

```rb
Rails.cache.redis.ping == "PONG"
```

and I'm trying to write a spec to stub this response so that I can control what it returns in tests.  However, usual simple expectations don't seem to work here as it's a method chain.

How would I test this code in RSpec?

Answer (score 0):

`Rails.cache.redis` returns an object of `Redis` class and the `ping` method is basically being called on an instance of the class.
Here is how you can stub the `ping` method.

```
allow_any_instance_of(Redis).to receive(:ping).and_return(DESIRED_MOCK_VALUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `before` block and stub the chain of messages

```
before do
  allow(Rails).to receive_message_chain(:cache, :redis, :ping).and_return("PONG")
end
```

Comment: [From the docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-11/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains): Chains can be arbitrarily long, which makes it quite painless to violate the Law of Demeter in violent ways, so you should consider any use of `receive_message_chain` a code smell.

Comment: @AlterLagos Thanks for the note. But in the OP example, such a bottleneck is not expected